# Delete mobile menu button

Tags: plugins, php, menus, css, editor

I'm doing a project for a web-based app.

It is the first time I use wordpress and I have found that I can not edit the template (the "edit" option does not appear in appearance.).

And I need to see the files to be able to remove the "hamburger" menu for mobile devices.

For now I'm not premmium.

In wix if the option to remove it, however I switch to wordpress because it loads much faster.

[image]

[![EDITOR?][2]][2]

I also do not find how to import the plugins.

When I press on plug in it sends me to another page that has this:

[image]

Comment: Judging from your screenshot I think you're on wordpress.COM, this site is only for questions of the self hosted version from wordpress.ORG. See https://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/

Answer (score 0):

It's best to remove these things with custom CSS - https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-css/ - if you can share the URL you are working on then we can have a look and assist with the CSS.

If you want to be able to install plugins and edit your themes/plugins you will need to setup a self-hosted version of WordPress - http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-com-vs-org/

Edit:

This is the code to remove the menu on mobile only:

```
@media (max-width: 782px) {
    .navigation-bar {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: poderdelapalabrasite.wordpress.com

Comment: I added the code above to remove the menu on mobile only via CSS. To remove for all devices remove the media query

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to up vote my answer if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

In general what you want to do is use something like Google Chrome's inspect feature so you can narrow down the name of the asset you are trying to edit.

You can use a media query with max-width using:

```
display:none !important;
```

Using !important is *essential* in WordPress because it overrides any other settings that may be set to the asset.

I **highly recommend** you look into setting up a child theme for edits like this, because then you can just update/reset your normal theme without losing any of these edits. This is a very good tutorial.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes